# error: invalid conversion from 'char**' to 'const char**'

Tags: c++, c

I've searched around and so far I haven't found a satisfactory answer to this question.

Why do these compile:

```
char c;
char const * d = &c;

char e;
char * const f = &e;

char* g;
char* const * h = &g;
```

but this doesn’t?

```
char* a;
char const ** b = &a;
```

> error: invalid conversion from 'char**' to 'const char**'

Comment: You've posted '**' wrong, it prints: `error: invalid conversion from 'char**' to 'const char**'`

Comment: @KittMedia the edit clearly fixes the formatting of the error message, with does improve reading

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463473/why-am-i-getting-an-error-converting-a-float-to-const-float