# Cython how to convert char** to const char**?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying to use Cython to write a wrapper around a C++ library. However, I am running into an issue now, as one of the functions in the library takes the parameter `const char**`. Apparently, C++ is unable to do this conversion, ([Why am I getting an error converting a ‘float**’ to ‘const float**’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463473/why-am-i-getting-an-error-converting-a-float-to-const-float)) which leaves me in a dilemma, as I am passing in a list of strings, let's call it `x`into the function, and I am trying to generate the corresponding char** object, let's call it `a`, using malloc and a for loop:

```
def f(x):
 cdef char** a = <char**> malloc(len(x) * sizeof(char*))
 for index, item in enumerate(x):
  a[index] = item
 ......
```

Is there a workaround here? The only thing I can think of is using `const_cast`, and I can't find any details of whether or not that is implemented in Cython....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code compiles in cPython V20.0.  Does that solve your problem?

```
# distutils: language = c++

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc

def f(x):
    cdef const char** a = <const char**> malloc(len(x) * sizeof(char*))
    for index, item in x:
        a[index] = item
```

Comment: This works as long as list `x` is referenced somewhere. After that the array points to memory locations that have been deallocated and possibly reused. Also changes in contents of `x` could cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There is this old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17511714/5781248) but I would implement `to_cstring_array` little bit differently (use of `strdup`, no `PyString_AsString`)

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libc.string cimport strdup

cdef char ** to_cstring_array(list strings):
    cdef const char * s
    cdef size_t l = len(strings)

    cdef char ** ret = <char **>malloc(l* sizeof(char *))
    # for NULL terminated array
    # cdef char ** ret = <char **>malloc((l + 1) * sizeof(char *))
    # ret[l] = NULL

    for i in range(l):
        s = strings[i]
        ret[i] = strdup(s)
    return ret
```