# How to pass a vector of strings to a function with a C-style pointer-to-C-string parameter

Tags: c++, pointers

I need to call the getList function below which comes from a library I cannot change.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//function already exists in a separate library, can't be changed
void getList(const char* list[], int count){};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vectorOfStrings = {"123" , "abc", "def", "456"};
    
    //call getList and pass vectorOfStrings and vectorOfStrings.size()
    getList(/*convert std::vector<std::string> to const char** */, vectorOfStrings.size());
    
    return 0;
}
```

I already asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74746498/7443051) and got an answer but I thought there might be a C++ way of doing this.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when… oh, okay, please proceed.

Comment: I afraid you need to write it yourself. 1. Allocate the array of pointers to char. 2. Iterate  and assign chPtrArray[n] = vectorOfString[n].data().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `std::vector<const char*>` to store the pointers of the string data stored in the original `std::vector<std::string>`.

This is a fast operation because you're copying the original data but mind that: this requires that the `const char*` passed to the function are not stored anywhere because **they'll become INVALID once the original string is deallocated** (you'll get undefined behavior).

```
std::vector<std::string> strings = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
std::vector<const char*> cstrings;
cstrings.reserve(strings.size());

std::transform(
    strings.begin(), 
    strings.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(cstrings), 
    [] (const auto& string) { return string.c_str();}
);

getList(cstrings.data(), cstrings.size());
```

Comment: I like the use of stl. Th syntax is a bit nicer with`std::ranges::transform` in C++20/C++23

Comment: Prior to C++23, you can still simplify this a little by removing the `back_inserter`, eg: `std::vector<const char*> cstrings(strings.size()); std::transform(strings.begin(), strings.end(), cstrings.begin(), [] (const auto& string) { return string.c_str(); } );`

Answer (score 3):

Given that the `vector` elements are not a C type, you'll need to construct an array to pass to the function:

```
const char **a = new const char *[vectorOfStrings.size()];
for (int i=0;i<vectorOfStrings.size();i++) {
    a[i] = vectorOfStrings[i].c_str();
}
getList(a, vectorOfStrings.size());
delete[] a;
```

Or, in a more C++ way:

```
std::vector<const char *> v2;
for (int i=0;i<vectorOfStrings.size();i++) {
    v2.push_back(vectorOfStrings[i].c_str());
}
getList(v2.data(), vectorOfStrings.size());
```

Comment: It will gove `const char *`, I believe. IMO `.data()` will be better

Comment: @EricPostpischil since C++11, `string.c_str()` and `string.data()` are required to return a pointer to the same null-terminated memory. The difference being that `.c_str()` is a read-only pointer, whereas `.data()` is read-only up to C++17 and then it is read/write pointer.